# Is it possible to create buttons using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 visualization of a graph where I get some data from a MySQL database. I want to create a button or something of the sort which the user can interact with (just like a button) based on the amount of data i get from my database.

For example: IF this is the array I get: [Blabla1, blabla2, blabla3]

I'll count those up and want to create 3 buttons. Is that possible in D3? I can't find anything in their documentation about buttons or likewise.

Comment: I would simply use a `<button>` element, why would you want to simulate it using D3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons are just DOM elements like everything else that D3 works with. There's nothing special about creating buttons as opposed to `div`s, SVG `circle`s or anything like that.

So your code would follow the usual pattern:

```
var data = [Blabla1, blabla2, blabla3];
d3.selectAll("button")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("button")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
  ...
```

Comment: Which attribute does a button need to appear? I have a new empty SVG, I append circles instead of buttons and they are created, but when I try buttons nothing appears.

Comment: There's no button element in SVG. You either need to "draw" one yourself or append the buttons to HTML.